# Optimization of Parse Trees

Tags: c++, tree

I've recently started to delve into Parse Trees with C++, because I have a certain task. An abstract syntax tree is generated with help of ast_parse (boost-library). This ast is then converted to a parse tree. There is a shared_ptr pointing to the root-node of the tree. Everything works fine here, the problem is as follows:

The input String can be something like this:

```
NumberOfViews > 3 AND NumberofViews > 3
```

or even worse

```
NumberOfViews > 3 OR not NumberOfViews > 3
```

(of course this evaluates always to true, and can be deleted entirely).

So there is a lot of redundancy in the tree and even logical problems, because the tree can get really big. I have to analyze the tree in an efficient way, and fix those issues (I would start by just fixing the duplicate problem). I don't need a solution, just some tips where to start or where to look, as I don't have any experience with parse trees so far.

#### Further Information:

The Parse Tree can get a bit more complex, with AND, ORs, INs, <=, != and even special functions can be invoked. They can have about 5000 characters. These filters are created by customers. Most of the time existing filters are copied into a new one, and no one cares about redundancy or illogical expressions. So I can't avoid those false expressions. My goal is to have the same Parse tree (as there is already a working one), just without redundancy. The Parse tree is generated from an ast; I thought about optimizing the ast first, so I don't have to deal with the parse tree itself. However, I have no idea how I can detect duplicates in a parse tree.

Comment: You need to explain what you want to achieve. If you are doing compiling those 'redundancies' will be taken care later, so no point in trying to eliminate them in the parser...and in any reasonable case you won't be able to do it if your strings are anything more powerful than propositional logic.

Comment: I have added Informations to my initial post, hope this helps.

Comment: "(of course this evaluates always to true, and can be deleted entirely)." -- That isn't clear from the information that's actually part of your question. By SQL's logic, for example, that may evaluate to "unknown", if NumberofViews is null. That said...

Comment: ...one possibility to start optimising it rewriting all filter expressions into a common form. For example, move all `OR` operators to the top level (this may make your filter longer at first: `a and (b or c)` becomes `(a and b) or (a and c)`), `and` operators below that, and get rid of `not` (make it part of the operator: store `not (a in (3, 4))` as `a not in (3, 4)` with a `not in` operator). Reorder the expressions to put a field first (`3 = a` becomes `a = 3`). Group by field and you have a realistic starting point for finding a lot of redundancy.

Comment: Because if you've done that, you can have purely field-based filters `b: >= 3, not < 3`, and look only for the redundancy in that. This is an approach I've been forced to take myself when filters got too large, and it works well for the sorts of filters I'm dealing with, but it may or may not be right for you.

Comment: @hvd's suggestions seem good, I think he should have writtem them as an answer. One thing I want to caution you about though is that in order to figure out if there are false expressions, you essentially have to solve the Satisfiability problem, which is NP-hard. Good luck with that.

Comment: @SchighSchagh Thanks. I didn't post it as an answer because whether it's appropriate depends heavily on the sort of data the OP is working with. It's a dead end if the OP's filters aren't field-based (`a < 29 and a + 1 < 30` cannot be simplified by that approach). If the OP says it does help, I can always write it as an answer later. :)

Comment: Do you mean optimizing the expression before it gets parsed, or rewriting the parse tree (the way you described), and then - afterwards - searching for duplicates in the optimized tree. I cannot optimize the expression itself, cause it is written by customers. And I can't change the syntax of filter expressions. Can you explain your approach a little bit further. Thanks in Advance

Comment: You still haven't answered the question what you want to do with these expressions: (1) transform the tree and split it out or (2) evaluate whether these expressions are true or false under an interpretation (an assignment to all variables). In both cases, you are better of not fiddling with the tree but establish a semantic representation, do the work (checking for unsatisfiable sentences, eliminating duplicates, etc) there and if you still need the minimal tree, generating it from the representation. There exist an effective procedure to do this as long as you don't have functions.

Comment: The ast-Tree is converted in a parse tree afterwards. The parse tree is evaluated against some input data. The task is about internet advertising. A user is tagged (a collection of information about the user), and certain Advertising banners have expression filters associated with them. The filter expression (in the form of a parse tree) is then compared with the Tag-Informations of the user in order to get the best Advertising. Thus, I don't want to spit out the tree, just used it to create a parse tree to compare it with some informations. How can I optimize the expression, if i'm not

Comment: parsing it before? Thanks in Advance (just ask if i missed some informations)

Comment: @user2791904 I didn't mean changing what users enter, I understand you have no control over that. Whether you optimise as the your tree is being built (during parsing) or run a separate optimisation pass after the fact doesn't really alter anything important. (By the way, I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "parse tree". I am familiar with the term, but I suspect you're using it with a slightly different meaning. I think your use, if I'm understanding you right, is better called "filter expression tree", as it no longer directly matches what's being parsed.)

Comment: The term parse tree is used in the already existing code, i just adapted it, don't know if the term is correct. So you mean, i should reorganize the tree, as you posted before, and and look only for the redundancy in field-based filters. Do you have an example?

Comment: @user2791904 Yes, that's what I meant, if that's what most of your filters look like. Sorry, I am not at liberty to post the actual code I'm using, but if you get stuck and can post some code highlighting a specific problem you're facing, I will be happy to take a look.

Comment: Thanks for you effort. Should i add questions here, or mark this as answer and post a new question if i have one?

Comment: I think that if you have a working starting point, and if you are allowed and willing to post it, it would be very helpful for others if you post your code as an answer to your own question. You can then post new questions as needed. Otherwise, I can think of good reasons both for and against continuing in this question, and it's a call you'll have to make. :)